# Handle Information for Volume

Tags: windows, driver, windbg

I use WinDBG to get handle information:

```
kd> !handle 430

PROCESS 85c91030  SessionId: 0  Cid: 0388    Peb: 7ffdc000  ParentCid: 01e8
    DirBase: 7ee841c0  ObjectTable: 8da023f0  HandleCount: 539.
    Image: svchost.exe

Handle table at 9a3da000 with 539 entries in use

0430: Object: 8480e038  GrantedAccess: 00100080 Entry: 8da01860
Object: 8480e038  Type: (844f9ac8) File
    ObjectHeader: 8480e020 (new version)
        HandleCount: 1  PointerCount: 2
        Directory Object: 00000000  Name: \ {HarddiskVolume2}
```

I know that most data is from _FILE_OBJECT but I cannot find out how {HarddiskVolume2} is determined. How does WinDBG get this information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it is Device Object Name for the partition in your harddisk

```
kd> !object \Device\HardDisk0\
Object: e13d5f58  Type: (812bd3c8) Directory
    ObjectHeader: e13d5f40 (old version)
    HandleCount: 1  PointerCount: 6
    Directory Object: e10077a0  Name: Harddisk0

    Hash Address  Type          Name
    ---- -------  ----          ----
     21  8123e5e0 Device        DR0
     33  e13d3a50 SymbolicLink  Partition0
     34  e13d3030 SymbolicLink  Partition1
     36  8126b030 Device        DP(1)0x7e00-0xfff2e4400+1
kd> !object \Device\HardDisk0\Partition1
Object: e13d3030  Type: (812bd1f8) SymbolicLink
    ObjectHeader: e13d3018 (old version)
    HandleCount: 0  PointerCount: 1
    Directory Object: e13d5f58  Name: Partition1
    Target String is '\Device\HarddiskVolume1'
```

you can query the reverse too using !driveinfo [dosdevicename]

```
kd> !driveinfo c:
Drive c:, DriveObject e13d3770
    Directory Object: e1004890  Name: C:
        Target String is '\Device\HarddiskVolume1'
        Drive Letter Index is 3 (C:)
    Volume DevObj: 8126bd98
    Vpb: 8123db20  DeviceObject: 8121b020
    FileSystem: \FileSystem\Ntfs
```

python script to get the mapping of all drives

```
from ctypes import *
ntdevs = create_string_buffer(15000)
b=windll.kernel32.GetLogicalDriveStringsA(sizeof(ntdevs),byref(ntdevs))
for i in range(0,b):
    print ntdevs[i],
print "\n"
dosdevs = create_string_buffer(15000)
for j in range(0,b,4):
    a=windll.Kernel32.QueryDosDeviceA(ntdevs[j]+ntdevs[j+1],byref(dosdevs),sizeof(dosdevs))
    for i in range(0,a):
        print dosdevs[i],
    print "\n"
```

exec

```
python qdd.py
C : \   D : \   E : \   F : \   G : \

\ D e v i c e \ H a r d d i s k V o l u m e 2

\ D e v i c e \ H a r d d i s k V o l u m e 3

\ D e v i c e \ H a r d d i s k V o l u m e 4

\ D e v i c e \ C d R o m 0

\ D e v i c e \ H a r d d i s k V o l u m e 5
```

edit

If you were on xp-sp3 this script can help you understand how windbg     retrieves the {hardiskvolume1}   this script also assumes certain things like level of kernel_handle_table be aware if there are lots of handles your probably can't index blindly like `handle * size + start of table`

In later os the OBJECT_HEADER structure is different There is no `NameInfoOffset` field
in the `OBJECT_HEADER` structure but a `TypeIndex`  you may need to 
modify this script to suit os > xp

```
r $t0 = (@@c++((sizeof(nt!_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY) / sizeof(unsigned long))) * ${$arg1})
r $t1 = (@$t0 + poi(poi(nt!ObpKernelHandleTable)))
r $t2 = (@@c++(#FIELD_OFFSET(nt!_OBJECT_HEADER  ,Body)))
r $t3 = (@@c++(#FIELD_OFFSET(nt!_FILE_OBJECT    ,DeviceObject)))
r $t4 = (@@c++(#FIELD_OFFSET(nt!_OBJECT_HEADER  ,NameInfoOffset)))
r $t5 = ((poi(@$t1) & 0xfffffff8 ) + @$t2)
r $t6 = (poi(@$t5 + @$t3) - @$t2 - @$t4)
.printf "%mu {%msu}" , @@c++(((nt!_FILE_OBJECT *) @@masm( @$t5 ))->FileName.Buffer ) ,  @$t6
```

executed like this

```
kd> $$>a< "xxx\getfilename.txt" 294
\Documents and Settings\NetworkService\NTUSER.DAT {HarddiskVolume1}
```

confirmation with !handle 294

```
PROCESS 80559c20  SessionId: none  Cid: 0000    Peb: 00000000  ParentCid: 0000
    DirBase: 00039000  ObjectTable: e1000b78  HandleCount: 230.
    Image: Idle

Kernel handle table at e1002000 with 230 entries in use

0294: Object: 810c20e0  GrantedAccess: 00000003 (Protected) Entry: e1002528
Object: 810c20e0  Type: (8127b900) File
    ObjectHeader: 810c20c8 (old version)
        HandleCount: 1  PointerCount: 4
        Directory Object: 00000000  Name: \Documents and Settings\NetworkService\NTUSER.DAT {HarddiskVolume1}
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I link the handle to this information?

Comment: I actually try to do what windbg does by code, but I fail to find the link

Comment: i added an old script that was pertinent to os xp-sp3 take a look you may need to study and adapt the script to suit os > xpsp3  ( look for OBJECT_HEADER differences )